# Uncheck rows in Repeater DataTable in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a data table filled using a Repetear. Also one column contains a checkbox property to select rows and, with a button, insert the checked rows into another table. After that, I use `Response.Redirect("Page.aspx")` to restart everything.
Is there a way to uncheck all the rows and clean the search result of the table without reload the page??
The table fills with 30,000 records and the page takes to much to load.

aspx:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        Data Table #1
    </div>

    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-StockAlmacen" data-toggle="table" data-sort-name="aiuda" data-sort-order="desc">
                <thead>
                    <tr>               
                        <th>Seleccionar</th>
                        <th>Id_Parte</th>
                        <th>Stock</th>
                        <th>Planta</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <asp:Repeater ID="rptStockAlmacen" runat="server">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <tr>
                                
                                <td>
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSeleccionar" runat="server" />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblId_Parte" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Id_Parte") %>' />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblStock" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Stock") %>' />
                                </td>

                                <asp:HiddenField ID="hiddenSeleccionar" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("Id_Parte") %>' />

                            </tr>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:Repeater>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

aspx.cs:

```
protected void btnInsertar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (RepeaterItem i in rptStockAlmacen.Items)
        {
            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)i.FindControl("chkSeleccionar");
            if (cb.Checked)
            {
                HiddenField hiddenSeleccionar = (HiddenField)i.FindControl("hiddenSeleccionar");
                SqlComm.SqlExecuteQueryInsert("insert into PartesSupervisadas (Id_Parte) values ('" + Int32.Parse(hiddenSeleccionar.Value) + "');");
            }
        }
       
        Response.Redirect("StockAlmacen.aspx");

    }
```

Comment: Why not a GridView? And if you are loading 30.000 items you might want to look into paging (and not the webforms kind). Because due to PostBack, all the data of those 30.000 items is send back and forth to the server in ViewState.

Comment: @VDWWD Is not more difficult to add columns and controls in GridView? I will look definitely for paging, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ouch you need to implement paging first and foremost. After that you could either call a js function to look for all checkboxes and clear them, you can do it on load or create a button that the user can click which fires the event. E.g. below

```
 function uncheckMe()
 { 
    var checkBox = document.getElementsByTagName('input'); 
    for(var i = 0; i < checkBox.length; i++)
    { 
      if(checkBox[i].type =='checkbox')
      { 
        checkBox[i].checked = false; 
      }
    }
 }
```